# Mac OS. How to create image from PNG data?

Tags: c++, c, cocoa, macos, png

I have an array of data that represents PNG:

```
unsigned short systemFontTexture[] = {

...
0x5089,0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,
0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,0x474E,0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,
0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,0x474E,0x474E,0x0A0D,0x5089,
...

}
```

Can I create PNG file using this data?
If yes, then HOW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create a data provider](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDataProviderCreateWithData) to serve up the data, and then [create an image with the data provider](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider).

Answer (score 2):

create a graphics context for an image and draw onto it. then save to png

Create a CGBitmapContext

draw your pixels

create a create a CGImage from from the CGBitmapContext

save the CGImage as PNG using CGImageDestination

Answer (score 0):

really close, just use ofstream to save your array as "picture.png". If your hex is correct and have the 8 byte signature before your pixels, it should work.